# Angular momentum commutation relations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

Does any operator $\mathbf{T} = (T_1,T_2,T_3)$ that satisfies the commutation relations $[T_i, T_j] = i\hbar\epsilon_{ijk}T_k$ represent an angular momentum operator?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, and that this may even be taken to be the definition of the angular momentum operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

The commutation relation merely means that the $T_i$ form the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$. There are $\mathrm{SU}(2)$s (and consequently $\mathfrak{su}(2)$s) which have nothing to do with angular momentum, e.g. the $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ in the [electroweak symmetry group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_interaction) $\mathrm{U}(1)\times\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Comment: sorry what's the difference between $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and $SU(2)$ ?

Comment: @SuperCiocia: That between a [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) and a [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group).

Comment: @SuperCiocia Isospin generators also satisfy that Lie algebra, but have nothing to do with angular momentum.

Comment: So if I had an operator that obeyed those commutation relations, is there a test (or some other way) to know whether or not it is angular momentum?

Comment: @SuperCiocia: No, the information what physical quantity a given group/operator represents is extrinsic to the group/operator. You can only say that anything has *not* these relations isn't angular momentum.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Some operators representing other physical quantities can be transformed so that they have the same algebraic structure of the angular momentum operators. For example, the inverse of "Jordan-Wigner transformation". Of course, you can think of them as effective angular momentum.